# Did the Prophet have a dog?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, reference-request

This [islamqa question](https://islamqa.info/en/6390), suggests:

> The hadeeth of Abu Hurayrah (may Allaah be pleased with him) who said: the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Jibreel came to me and said: ‘I came to you yesterday and nothing prevented me from entering except that there was a statue by your door, and there was a curtain in your house with images on it, and **there was a dog in the house.** So tell someone to cut the head off the statue by your door, so it will look like a tree; tell someone to cut up the curtain and make it into floor-cushions that will be stepped on; and **tell someone to put the dog outside**.’” So the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) did that.
>
> (Narrated by Abu Dawood, al-Tirmidhi and Ahmad).

The source is unclear and these scholars had compiled some da'if hadith.

**Question:** What is the reliability of this hadith (is it sahih or da'if)?

Comment: Relevant: [Abu Daud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/34/139) and [Tirmizi](https://sunnah.com/urn/730300) also see related hadith in [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/37/126).